# How to get the Categories list only from the current Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this simple Post Loop through standard query to display posts in my home page:

```
<?php
 if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This will give me below posts list:
1) This is post one - Category: Apple
2) This is post Two - Category: Grapes
3) This is post Three - Category: Cherry
4) This is post Four - Category: Mango
5) This is post Five - Category: Apple
6) This is post Six - Category: Mango
7) This is post Seven- Category: Grapes

I wanted to show all the Categories in the above Loop as drop-down; not all the categories in my WordPress.
I have other categories as well in my WordPress, such as Kiwi, Melon, Banana, etc...I don't want to show them in my categories drop-down list.

I tried this:

```
if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) : 
    echo '<select><option>Select category...</option>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
        echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; 
    endforeach;
    echo '</select>';
endif;
```

It is showing all the Categories in my WordPress. How do I limit the categories showing in this list only from the above loop.

Comment: above loop means? you want to show those categories which are assigned to particular post?

Comment: @prashant, i have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i have create code and run on my end. it works fine. you will be able to get all categories ids which has assigned to post in loop. Test below code

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    $catarray = array();

    // Start the Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $category_detail = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    
        //here you will be able to see all category detail. print this object
        //i am assuming $category_detail['term_id'];
        if( ! in_array( $category_detail[0]->term_id, $catarray, true ) ) {
            $catarray[] = $category_detail[0]->term_id;
        }
    endwhile;
endif;

foreach( $catarray as $cat ) {
    $thisCat = get_category( $cat );
    echo "<li>" . $thisCat->name . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: I changed `$catarray[] = $category_detail[0]->term_id;` to `$catarray[] = $category_detail[0]->name;`; this gave me list of the categories in the loop as `Array ( [0] => Apple [1] => Grape [2] => Cherry [3] => Mango) `

Comment: how do get this categories in a `<li>`? I have tried `foreach`; that did not gave any results.

Comment: yes see my below answer. i have corrected in it after executing code in my demo wp. Now you can see there you getting category ids. Now you can get all details in for each loop with that category ids. using wp cat functions.

Comment: `foreach` loop is not producing the list, its blank

Comment: have you assigned category to posts?

Comment: you have to manipulate this $catarray.  Try and debug why its not working at your side by print_r($catarray) OR war_dump

Comment: yes, posts has categories assigned. `print_r($catarray)` is producing the category names in plain text as mentioned in first comment. When using `foreach` loop not getting list.  Can you share the `foreach` you have tested, if.

Comment: no not to hold names. you have to hold ids. see my this code. you will get idea. paste this code.